# How to shorten this conditional in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to assign two constants on one condition. I thought about:

```js
const success = thing ? valueS1 : valueS2;
const failure = thing ? valueF1 : valueF2;
```

and

```js
if (thing) {
    const success = valueS1;
    const failure = valueF1;
}
else {
    const success = valueS2;
    const failure = valueF2;
}
```

It's valid but I don't really like the way how it looks, maybe there is a trick to shorten this up?

Comment: Don't forget that the code should be clean and readable by an other developer. Shortening these clear statements can make it harder to understand

Comment: Is the valueS1,valueF1,valueS2,valueF2 constants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can destructure the new variable names from an array taken from the conditional operator:

```
const [success, failure] = thing ? [valueS1, valueF1] : [valueS2, valueF2];
```

Like the comment on the question notes, while this is *possible* code to write to make things shorter, I'm not so sure it's a great idea, because it looks a bit odd, and the intent isn't quite as clear. Having so many independent variable names is a *little bit* of a code smell - you might consider an object or array instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
const [success,failure] = thing ? [valueS1,valueF1] : [valueS2,valueF2];
```